# Is there a libary for GUI Development ala Simulink

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop

For a University project I have to develop a Logic-Circuit-Builder.

The GUI is supposed to work like Matlab's Simulink:

- Select some Object like an OR-Gatter,
- Drag and Drop it somewhere on your drawing-panel,
- Connect it with some other Object with a wire or something.

I think everybody used this kind feature sometime in his life in some software so I hope you know what I have in mind.

I also know, that this task is a lot harder than it sounds.

1. How do you know which Object is selected when you click into the panel?
2. What about overlapping Objects?
3. Is there any auto-alignment?
4. What about the wiring when you move an object?

and so on and on...

But now to my Question:

These tasks got solved so many times by so many softwares Like Simulink, uml-Designers, Apple's Logic or Cubase, Microsoft Visio, Blender...

What is this Kind of GUI called and are there any Libarys or Frameworks for this kind of GUI?

PS I tried Google for several hours but I just don't know how to articulate what I am looking for...

Thank you for your time